# Baffling HTML/CSS icons display on all of my iOS devices, but no others

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

I am baffled by a strange problem I'm encountering.

On a standard web browser, you'll see some social media icons, like this screenshot:

[image: icons]

This is exactly how they appear in Safari on my iPhone, my iPad Mini, and my colleague's iPad Mini too.

However - this next screenshot shows what they look like on the client's iPad:

[image: icon fail]

I can't for the life of me work it out. I see the same problem on iOS devices viewed via a remote VCN simulator too, but can't fathom why this is.

It's unlikely to make a difference(?), but me and my colleague are in the UK, whilst the client is in America. All parties have tried clearing their cache, reloading, etc. Still works fine for us but not for them.

My colleague and I have tried viewing on different wireless networks, over 3G, etc. Again, it makes no difference.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks you're missing a reference to http://your-site.com/images/aarp/socials/socials@2x.png

on line 1747:
http://your-site.com/?css=aarp-css/alterna-style.v.1366969865